# Geometry : Incircle of isosceles triangle and Menelaus

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

**Geometry Problem:**

Let $ABC$ be an isosceles triangle with $AC = BC$. It's incircle touches $AB$ at $D$,$ BC$ at $E$. A line goes through A and intersects incircle at $F$ and $G$. Line $AB$ intersects $EF$ and $EG$ in $K$ and $L$ respectively. Prove $DK=DL$.

This problem is supposed to be solved by using menelaus. I extended some line segments and applied menelaus wherever I could but couldn't do it. Can some shed some light on it?

**Edit:** [image]

My main focus is on $∆GEF$, by applying menelaus here we get $ \frac{FA}{AG} \frac{GL}{LE} \frac{EK}{FK}=1$ and also consider $∆ACD$ and $∆BCD$, we get $\frac{DN}{NC} \frac{CW}{WA} \frac{AK}{KD} = 1$ and $\frac{DP}{PC} \frac{CE}{EB} \frac{BL}{LD}=1$. I am not sure how they would be of any help.

Comment: Can you show us a picture of your extended segments and how you applied Menelaus?

Comment: @cosmo5 I think transversal can lie totally outside of  triangle for menelaus to apply. Can you elaborate on "angle chasing"

Comment: Then shouldn't it be $EK/FK$ instead of $EW/WK$? I came upon a solution on AOPS, though I haven't gone fully through it.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I will edit it. Can you post the link to aops thread?

Comment: Clever find of cyclic quadrilateral: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h225453p1251781

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The tangent line $AH$ to the circle and $HE \>|| \>KL$ assure

$$\angle AHF = \angle HEF = \angle FKA = \alpha$$

which makes AFHK cyclic and leads to

$$\angle KHA = \angle KFA = \angle GFE = \angle CEG = \angle LEB = \beta$$

Along with $\angle HAK = \angle EBL$ and $HA = EB$, the $\triangle HKA$ and $\triangle ELB$ are congruent. Therefore $KA = LB$ and, in turn, $DK = DL$.